# Can't invoke setspn from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, spn

I need to call Setspn.exe from PowerShell.
but any tries are fail:

```
setspn;
Setspn;
invoke-expression "setspn";
start-process setspn;
```

But i can launch cmd, and i can call setspn from command line.

Comment: "Fail" covers a lot of territory.  Can you be a little more specific/helpful?

Comment: The term 'setspn' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a
 path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: Check your `$env:PATH` and see if it contains the path to `setspn.exe`.

Comment: I can run it from a standard Powershell prompt. Returns standard help output to the output stream. Sounds like a configuration problem to me. like mjolinor says - more info needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble with PowerShell open it up in CMD.

```
PS C:\> cmd /c 'setspn'
```

Remember CMD only returns text not objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the invoke operator `&`

```
& 'C:\Windows\System32\setspn.exe'
```

If you want to add parameters to the setspn call, you can put them in an array and add it to the invocation

```
$param = ('-L','SANDY.sqladmin.lan')
& 'C:\Windows\System32\setspn.exe' $param
```